# C++ socket read() inside child thread giving SIGABRT

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I'm handling incoming connections to a socket in separate `std::thread` for each client connection. So when trying to do a `read()` from the socket, the program crashes.

```
std::thread in_conn_th(handle_new_connection, in_socket);  // <-- creating a new thread and passing the handle_new_connection function into the thread with the socket descriptor param
```

Here is the description of `handle_new_connection()`

```
waiterr::operation_codes waiterr::Waiter::handle_new_connection(int incoming_socket) {
    std::cout << "Here comes " << incoming_socket << "\n";

    char buffer[30000] = {0};

    int val_read = read(incoming_socket, buffer, 30000);  // <-- Error

    std::cout << "Here comes 2\n";

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl << std::endl;
    write(incoming_socket, "Some response", 13);

    std::cout << "* Msg sent *\n";
    close(incoming_socket);

    return operation_codes(OK);
}
```

Error

```
shantanu@Shantanus-MacBook-Pro webserver % ./test1.o                                                   
* Waiting for new connection *
libc++abi: terminating
Here comes 4
zsh: abort      ./test1.o
```

If I'm just calling `handle_new_connection()` without spawning a new thread, the operation is successful and response is shown in the client.

So I'm pretty sure its about some thread thing that I'm unaware of.

Environment -
Apple M1 Silicon; running g++ natively on ARM.

Edit
function definition for `handle_new_connection()`

```
static enum operation_codes handle_new_connection(int incoming_socket);
```

Comment: The only way that `read()` call can fail given the code shown is if `incoming_socket` is corrupted. Is `waiterr::Waiter` a namespace or a class? If the latter, then is `handle_new_connection()` static or non-static? These make a big difference in how and where `int incoming_socket` is passed to `handle_new_connection()` on the call stack. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `waiterr::Waiter` is a class. `handle_new_connection` is static

Comment: Then there is no way the `read()` shown can fail, provided `in_socket` and `incoming_socket` have the same value. However, the `std::cout << buffer` could fail, if `read()` returns *exactly* 30000 bytes so that `buffer` is not null-terminated. Use `cout.write(buffer, val_read)` instead (after validating that `val_read` is not `<= 0`)

Comment: What is "*libc++abi: terminating*" about in your output? Are you terminating your app before the thread has a chance to use the socket?

Comment: I'm not able to see the second cout statement printed. So that ensures there's something going on above that

Comment: Yeah I don't know what is libc++abi. I'm not terminating the app myself

Comment: One thread-thing that has bit me in the past is when a function tried to allocate more stack space than the thread's stack had room for, causing the thread's stack variables to partially overwrite the stack variables of another thread; chaos ensued.  You might try at least temporarily replacing the `char buffer[30000]` with `char * buffer = new char[30000]; [...]; delete [] buffer;` just to see if it helps.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I used `pthread_t` instead of `std::thread` and it worked just fine.

Instead of

```
std::thread in_conn_th(handle_new_connection, in_socket);
```

I used

```
pthread_t in_conn_th;
pthread_create(&in_conn_th, NULL, handle_new_connection, (void*)(&in_socket));
```

And changed the function definition to receive the `void *`

Do not forget to include `pthread.h` header.